# Why can't i plot an actual pie chart with percentages?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

There are two columns in my data set Q6.1,

```
 count(market_segment)  market_segment
1 201                   Complementary
2 2309                  Corporate
3 6513                  Direct
4 5836                  Groups
5 7472                  Offline TA/TO
6 17729                 Online TA

Showing 1 to 6 of 6 entries, 2 total columns
```

I am using this code

```
ggplot(Q6.1, aes(x="", y= 'count(market_segment)', fill = market_segment))+ 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1)+coord_polar("y", start=0)+
   geom_text(aes(label = paste0('count(market_segment')))
```

Comment: Hello there and welcome to stack overflow. We are strangers on the internet that don't have your data or have a picture of the resulting plot that can be diagnostic. Would you mind including a data sample with your code example? Snippets of data can be easy shared by copy-pasting the output of `dput(Q6.1)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `coord_polar` to convert the bar chart to a pie chart, and add the percentage labels using `geom_text`. Given the unwieldy column names, perhaps you should also convert this to proportions first:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df$percent <- df$`count(market_segment)`/ sum(df$`count(market_segment)`)

ggplot(df, aes(x = 1, y = percent, fill = market_segment)) + 
  geom_col(color = "gray90", width = 1) +
  geom_text(aes(x = c(1.1, rep(1, 5)), label = scales::percent(percent)),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Pastel1", name = "Market segment") +
  theme_void()
```

[image]